# In Excel 2016, using VLOOKUP and trying to count only cells in a column that return a value

Tags: vlookup, countif, excel-2016

Using COUNTIF to count occurrences in a column with VLOOKUP formulas. Can I count only cells that return a value, without erasing the VLOOKUP in the cells that don't return a value?

I've tried using COUNTBLANK, but it doesn't return the correct value of "blank" cells (that return no value). Here is the VLOOKUP formula:

=IF(VLOOKUP($A6,'VLookup All'!$A$11:$T$2922,15,FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP($A6,'VLookup All'!$A$11:$T$2922,15,FALSE))